# Autofac registration issue

Tags: c#, autofac, outlook-addin

I'm very new to Autofac and am having an issue.

The following code is how I register my dependencies, and afterwards I check if they are both (blah1/blah2) registered and both return 'true'.

```
public AddInBootstrapper(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace session)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.Register(c => new OutlookService(session)).As<IOutlookService>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<EmailPrintService>().As<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();

        _container = containerBuilder.Build();

        var blah1 = _container.IsRegistered<IOutlookService>();
        var blah2 = _container.IsRegistered<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();
    }
```

When I later click my wired up Outlook ribbon button, the first one (blah1) shows as still registered, the second one (blah2) comes back 'false'

```
private void printNowButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var blah1 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Core.IsRegistered<IOutlookService>();
        var blah2 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Core.IsRegistered<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();

        var outlookSvc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Core.Resolve<IOutlookService>();
        var printSvc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Core.Resolve<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();

        var folder = outlookSvc.GetFolder(@"public folders\all public folders\testpf\docprinttest\anotherfolder");

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item in folder.Items)
        {
            if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                // print attachments
            }

            printSvc.PrintItem(item);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

**Edit (here is the rest of the code):**

The process starts off when the Outlook add-in loads:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private AddInBootstrapper _core;
    public AddInBootstrapper Core
    {
        get { return _core; }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _core.Dispose();
    }

    public override void BeginInit()
    {
        _core = new AddInBootstrapper(this.Application.Session);

        base.BeginInit();
    }

    // some VSTO generated code here (non-modified)
}
```

IPrintService.cs:

```
namespace MRP.Outlook.DocPrint.Core.Services.Interfaces
{
  public interface IPrintService<T>
  {
      void PrintItem(T item);
  }
}
```

EmailPrintService.cs:

```
namespace MRP.Outlook.DocPrint.Core.Services
{
  public class EmailPrintService : IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>
{
    public EmailPrintService()
    {
    }

    public void PrintItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item)
    {
        //item.PrintOut();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Printing: " + item.Subject);
    }
  }
}
```

That is it, the Add-in loads, they are both registered, I click the button - one is registered, one isn't.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you're showing us, but in the code you're not.

Comment: That may be the case, but I don't see how. The rest is added above now.

Comment: Obviously something to do with the Generic Interface IPrintService, as if I remove the generic from that interface it remains registered in the container.

Answer (score 4):

To make a completely uninformed guess, is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` a COM type in an embedded interop assembly? (See the "No PIA" feature in .NET 4).

If so, it is possible that there are multiple copies of the type, tied together only by the GUID applied to them. The CLR allows this, treating them as assignable to each other, but when the types are compared (e.g. to look up a registration) they will differ.

I don't know of a direct workaround, but you can test out this theory by creating your own `MailItem` type that wraps the Outlook one. Using your own type as the generic parameter should resolve the issue. Best of luck!